# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3) showing in flutter doctor

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

when I run `flutter doctor` I have this error:

[image]

although I have flutter and dart plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the Flutter and Dart plugins installed in Android Studio 4.0. If so, you can keep using it and ignore this error.

This is trying to tell you that you also have IntelliJ installed in your computer. You can also use IntelliJ to develop Flutter apps, but you have to install Flutter and Dart plugins on it as well. If you will keep using Android Studio, just ignore this line of error in `flutter doctor`.